# Is it possible to translate using i18n inside a select dialog box

Tags: javascript, quasar, vue-i18n

I have a `<q-select>` dropdown box, that is populated with a list of languages.  What I would like is to have this box display the list of languages in its translated version.  For example, if the select language is English then the box would show "English".  However if the selected language is German, then the box would show "Englisch".

This is my select dialog and also how I am getting the values:

```
<q-select v-model="model" :options="options" option-label="language" option-value="text">
                    <template v-slot:prepend>

created: function () {
        let options = this.$store.state.languages.options;
        this.options = options;

        this.options.map(x=>{
            if(x.code == this.$store.state.globals.language){
                this.model = x;
            }
        });
    },
```

This is being populated from a vuex store:

```
export default function () {
    return {
        options: [ //please alphabetize options as they are added
            {language:'Dutch',code:'nl-NL',flag:'https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/netherlands-emoji.png',text:'Begin met spelen'},
            {language:'English',code:'en',flag:'https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/united-states-emoji.png',text:'Start Playing'},
            {language:'German',code:'de-DE',flag:'https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/germany-emoji.png',text:'Jetzt Spielen'},
            {language:'Spanish',code:'es-ES',flag:'https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/spain-emoji.png',text:'Empezar a jugar'},
            {language:'Portuguese',code:'pt-BR',flag:'https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/portugal-emoji.png',text:'Comece a Jogar'}
        ]
    };
}
```

Each of the languages has a translation of "language" that I would like to use in the `q-select`.  My initial thought was inside the q-select I would then just call `$t('language')` for the option-label, however that does not do anything.

One other option that I thought of is to loop through the options creating a new local version, and then apply the translations as it loops through.  In theory that should work, but I have not tried that option yet.
I am open to any other ideas or options that you might have.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate the options dynamically - you should provide a function for the `option-value` prop:

```html
<q-select v-model="model" :options="options" option-label="language" :option-value="translatedLanguage">

methods:
{
  translatedLanguage(option)
  {
    return option ? this.$t(option.text) : null;
  }
}
```